# How can I programmatically get memory, thread and CPU usuage from within my Java application?

Tags: java

The question says it all!

How can I programmatically get memory, thread and CPU usuage from within my Java application?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the various static methods in [ManagementFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html), like `getOperatingSystemMXBean()`, `getMemoryMXBean()` and `getThreadMXBean()`.

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html